# Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать на Tilda автоматическое изменение описания товара или при выборе одного параметра- остальные тоже меняются

Tags: tilda

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Прикреплю пример, того что нужно ниже [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.